# Homotopy between two curves over complex numbers

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, differential-geometry

I need help filling the gaps in the proof of an homotopy between  the unit circle and the  curve consinting of two circles with radius 1\4 and centers 1\2 and -1\2 joint by the closed interval [1\4,-1\4]

First I need to construct the homotopy who doesnt touch the points 1\2 and -1\2 (this is because i will need this homotopy  to compute a complex integral that is not holomorphic over these points).

So I need to give a parametrization of these two curves $\gamma$ and $\phi$ so I can have the deformation followed by the homotopy [0,$\pi$/2] So the curve $\phi$ can be parametrizated in the natural way this is $\phi$(s) = 1\2 + $ e^{is}$\4 but $\gamma$ shoulde be parametrizated in a way it adapts to $\phi$ , these can be obtained writing $\gamma$(s) =1\2 + $ke^{is}$ where $k$ should satisfy $|1/2 + ke^{is}|=1$ in case this have sense my teacher told me the value of $k$ must be 
$$
k =  \frac{\sqrt{\cos^2 s + 3} - \cos s}{2}
$$
( * I cannot show this , so i need help here )

$$ H(s,t) =t \gamma(s) + (1-t) \phi(s),\\
 H:[0 , 4\pi + 1]  \times[0,1]
  \to  \mathbb C - \{1/2 , -1/2\}.
$$

Also how do I find a parametrization of the curve $\gamma$ over the interval $[\phi/2 , \phi]$?

Thanks

Comment: Wow. I edited your question some to clean up the math a bit, but I'd like to suggest you try re-writing it in short, mostly declarative, sentences. Really short. You've got these run-on things that makes it almost impossible to follow what you're saying ... and this is stuff that I do every day. Clear questions get better answers in general.

Answer (score 1):

I too cannot make much sense out of your mangled description. But please note that your curve lies neatly in the interior of the unit circle and that vertical lines connect the points of your curve to the unit circle without any twists or crossings. An obvious homotopy would leave the $x$ values alone while moving the positive $y$ values proportionally up from your curve to the unit circle, and the negative $y$ values down to the unit circle by the same proportion. That is, if your curve is given by $\alpha : [0,1] \to \Bbb C: t \mapsto x(t) + iy(t)$, and is such that $y(t) \ge 0$ for $t \in [0, 1/2]$ and $y(t) \le 0$ for $t \in [1/2,1]$  then the homotopy is
$$h(t,u) = \begin{cases}x(t) + i\left((1-u)y(t) + u\sqrt{1 - x^2(t)}\right ) & t \in [0,1/2] \\x(t) + i\left((1-u)y(t) - u\sqrt{1 - x^2(t)}\right) & t \in [1/2,1]\end{cases}$$